# Variable is changing when it should not

Tags: powershell

I have a pretty simple PS script set up to take 3 parameters (remote HTTP file, local copy path, filter list of files desired) and then download the files requested. I am using `System.Net.WebClient` and the method `DownloadFile`. I am currently faced with a really odd error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find
>   a part of the path 
>   'C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\download.bls.gov\pub\time.series\la\la.area_type'."
>   At
>   C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\HTTP_based_downloader.ps1:45
>   char:13
>   +             $wc.DownloadFile($sourceFile, $targetFile);
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

But if I `Write-Host` before and after the call to download the file the target path is valid. When I debug into that line it does have the correct paths.

The correct value should be:

```
C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\la\la.area_type
```

But it is being changed somewhere to:

```
C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\download.bls.gov\pub\time.series\la\la.area_type
```

The `$sourceFile` is set to:

```
download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.area_type
```

This is the offending line:

```
$wc.DownloadFile($sourceFile, $targetFile);
```

The full code:

```
param(
    # Required. Download source location (website).
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $URL,
    # Required. Download target location (local drive).
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $destinationFolder,
    # Required. File containing list of files to download. Must exist in same location as this script.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $fileList
)

process
{
    # Setup params
    if (!($destinationFolder.EndsWith("\"))) {
        $destinationFolder = $destinationFolder + "\";
    }

    if (!($URL.EndsWith("/"))) {
        $URL = $URL + "/";
    }

    # Get root domain for use in determining $soureFile
    [uri]$URL = $URL;
    $baseURL = $URL.Authority;

    # Get list of files requested from filter list file.
    $filesRequested =  gc $fileList;

    # Set up the web client for downloading the files.
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;

    # Get list of files available at $URL
    $fileItems = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $URL | select -expand links | select -expand href;

    # Loop through list of available files and find matches in filter list.
    $fileItems | foreach {
        if ($filesRequested.Contains((split-path $_ -Leaf))) {        
            $sourceFile = $baseURL + $_;
            $targetFile = $destinationFolder + (split-path $_ -Leaf);
            Write-Host $sourceFile;
            Write-Host $targetFile;
            #Write-Host "Getting: "$sourceFile "Destination: "$targetFile;
            $wc.DownloadFile($sourceFile, $targetFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling this:

```
.\HTTP_based_downloader.ps1 "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/" "C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\la\" "la-file-list.txt"
```

Contents of `la-file-list.txt`:

> la.area la.area_type la.contacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by invalid source-path.
`$url.Authority` value doesn't include a protocol name, which made the value a string and not a URI.

This made the webclient use `DownloadFile(string,string)` overload with a relative local path as source instead of `Downloadfile(uri,string)`. A solution for the script above would be something like:

```
$baseurl = "$($URL.Scheme)://$($URL.Authority)"
```

Comment: The sourceFile is fine. It is the targetFile that is getting garbled.

Comment: Editing question with used calls.

Comment: My bad, didn't read the error properly. Hmm.. A good tip in general is to use parameter names, like `.\HTTP_based_downloader.ps1 -URL "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/" -destinationFolder "C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\la\" -fileList "la-file-list.txt"`. Are you getting the same error then?

Comment: Could you include the output of `Write-Host "Getting: $sourceFile Destination: $targetFile"` (REPLACE with the commented out command in your script) for a file that fails(do all files fail?)

Comment: All files fail the out put looks good though: `Getting:  download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.contacts Destination:  C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\la\la.contacts`

Comment: Gave you the points because you got me thinking about the source path.

Comment: Hehe, I was guessing for sourcepath error at first as you can see. Wrong target path returns a different error. Weird "bug" though.

Answer (score 3):

Found the reason for the manipulation of the path. It is because in the code I am getting the domain:

```
[uri]$URL = $URL;
$baseURL = $URL.Authority;
```

This strips off the "http://". If PS thinks this is not a valid URI it then *appends the source location to the path where the script was called.* So, because I am running the script from: `C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads` it is adding the remote path starting here such that I get:

```
C:\Users\lrichards\Desktop\US-LMI\PowerShell\BLS_Downloads\download.bls.gov\pub\time.series\la\la.area_type
```

If I prepend "http://" to the `$baseURL` all works as desired.

Why is it assuming that if there is no "http" prefix it is is not a valid URL I have no idea.

Relevant documentation link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> If the BaseAddress property is not an empty string ("") and address
>   does not contain an absolute URI, address must be a relative URI that
>   is combined with BaseAddress to form the absolute URI of the requested
>   data. If the QueryString property is not an empty string, it is
>   appended to address.